# ecma6 shortest for loop with if check

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, ecmascript-6

what is the shortest way to achieve this for loop in ecmascript 6:

```
var data = {
        sales: [
            {
                name: "Jim Frost",
                region: "USA East",
                phone: "212-555-1212",
                email: "jfrost@acme-travel.com"
            },
            {
                name: "Jan Smith",
                region: "USA West",
                phone: "310-555-1212",
            }
        ]
};
```

here is my attempt to see if the key is equal to my manually set variable, then i change that key item's field, if not, i change it to something else.

```
var str = '0'; // could also be an integer
for (var key in data.sales) {
  key ===  str ? data.sales[key].region = 'StateChosen' : data.sales[key].region = 'stateEliminated';
}
```

what is the shortest way to achieve this using ecma6, object.keys, map, filter, every, etc methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for of` loop with destructuring assignment and `.entries()` would help.

```
for (let [k, v] of data.sales.entries())
  v.region = k == str ? 'StateChosen' : 'stateEliminated';
```

```js
var data = {
        sales: [
            {
                name: "Jim Frost",
                region: "USA East",
                phone: "212-555-1212",
                email: "jfrost@acme-travel.com"
            },
            {
                name: "Jan Smith",
                region: "USA West",
                phone: "310-555-1212",
            }
        ]
};
var str = '0';

for (var [k, v] of data.sales.entries())
  v.region = k == str ? 'StateChosen' : 'stateEliminated';

console.log(data);
```

Comment: how does it change if I pass `true` or `false` instead of stateChosen and stateEliminated?

Comment: @moaningalways: Then it would be `v.region = k == str;`

Comment: how can i make sure that the `str` is among the keys before doing the loop?

Comment: @moaningalways: `if (str in data.sales) { /* your code */ }`

Answer (score 2):

Your example could be done just by doing:

```
data.sales.forEach(el => el.region = 'stateEliminated'); // Change every region to eliminated
data.sales[str].region = 'StateChosen'; // Change back the selected to StateChosen.
```

Note: **I am assuming** that `str` is a valid key in `data.sales`.

Comment: This could lead to a NPE if the key doesn't exist in the `sales` object.

Comment: You don't even need the parentheses around `el` ;)

Comment: how can i check if the key exists and the do what you do?